# Error when activating virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

Getting error message "Badly placed ()'s" when activating a virtual environment.

I created a new virtual environment an when trying to activate the venv with "source VEnv/newvenv/bin/activate" I just get an output with the error message.
The error also appears for existing VEnvs.

What do I need to do to get my VEnv activated?

Comment: Could you please add the error that you get in your question? And the command that you used to create the virtual environment?

Comment: This error message is printed by the shell. I'm guessing you are attempting to evaluate Python code in the shell. But since the question contains no code and no error message, I'm voting to close as unclear. See also the guidance for including a [mre].

Comment: The error message is -as written- "Badly placed ()'s". And I created the VEnv with the command "python3 –m venv myVirtEnv"

Comment: And yes, the error comes from within a shell when trying to activate the VEnv.

Comment: The error "*Badly placed ()'s*" suggests that it's a wrong shell. Perhaps it's sh/ash/dash while virtualenv activation script requires bash or zsh.

Comment: I am running csh. How can I change that? 
It is on my MacBook with macOS Catalina 10.15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For csh shell you need to do

```
source VEnv/newvenv/bin/activate.csh
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously this is due to a change from Apple. See: https://insights.dice.com/2019/06/12/macos-catalina-zsh-bash-xcode-11/

From that article I found how to switch the Shell back to zsh: If you want to give it a shot, head into the Apple Menu > System Preferences > Users & Groups > click the lock icon > control-click your name in the list of users > Advanced Options > Login shell > Zsh > OK

That solved the issue for me.
Thanks to phd who brought me into this direction to get it solved!